# Can't get LocalDate to Parse correctly

Tags: java, localdate

```
String date = "08/02/2022 Tuesday";
DateTimeFormatter LONG_DATE_FORMAT_ddMMyyyyEEEE = ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy EEEE");
LocalDate.parse(date, LONG_DATE_FORMAT_ddMMyyyyEEEE);
```

I'm getting a DateTimeParseException with the following message: Text 08/02/2022 Tuesday' could not be parsed at index 11.

I suppose this is an issue with the EEEE side of my format, but I can't seem to understand what should replace it.

This is java 1.8.0_311

Comment: What locale do you work with?

Comment: Hint: try *formatting* a value with that `DateTimeFormatter`, and that may well suggest what's wrong. Like Lajos, my guess is that it's a locale issue

Comment: It was indeed a Locale issue, first time with this package, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

We need DateTimeFormatter class to format date string properly. We also need to convert the string date to LocalDate object and back to string again to display. The DateTimeParseException class handles any undesired outcomes.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

        String date = "08-02-2022 Tuesday";
        DateTimeFormatter pattern = 
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy eeee");

        // parsing string date to LocalDate obj
        // The part you were missing 
        LocalDate formattedDate = LocalDate.parse(date, pattern);

        // Again converting to string 
        System.out.println(formattedDate.format(pattern));
        }

        // handling exception for unparseble dates
        catch(DateTimeParseException x){
            System.out.println("The given date cannot be parsed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

LocalDate contains of a day, month, and year (Variation between +999999999-12-31 and -999999999-12-31)

Things like time and other values are rejected by the parsing. If you would like the day of the week, you can use a function like:

```
    // Parses the date
    LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse("2018-11-27");

    // Prints the day
    System.out.println(dt.getDayOfWeek());
```

Comment: I think this might be a better solution to the issue. I'm probably gonna go with this one, thank you.

Comment: I agree with your thinking, and I don't think you should use any code that works "For now" every project, but sometimes its better to use something that works around the problem to pursue progress.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
String date = "08/02/2022 Tuesday";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy EEEE");
    
LocalDate time = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
System.out.println(time.format(formatter));
```

Comment: Then it must be a Locale issue, as I'm working with a remote PC on another country. TY.